# MongoDB/Mongoose joining based on name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a product schema that has a properties array with varying amounts of objects. One object looks like this:

> [{ property: 'Color', value: 'Black' }, { property: 'Length', value: '1 inch' }]

Each product has a random amount of properties. The problem is that I can't lookup a product and get their properties with its identifier.

Below is the product schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let product = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: new Date()},
    language: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String },
    articlenumber: { type: String },
    name: { type: String },
    properties: { type: [{}] }
});

module.exports = product;
```

I also have a property schema from my properties collection with an identifier.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let property = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    categoryPropertyId: { type: String },
    language: { type: String },
    name: { type: String, unique: true }
});

module.exports = property;
```

> { id: ObjectID, categoryPropertyId: '317', language: 'US', name: 'Color' }

I would like to get a product and join based on its name and language and get the categoryPropertyId.

Would this be possible with mongoose? I could do it with javascript loops but would prefer something like joining.

I've looked at $lookup and populate but I'm not that skilled with mongoose. Any help is appreciated!

**A product**

```
{
    _id: 5b3f18d93098293c4ab0ca4a,
    created_at: ‘2018-07-06 09:22:45.377’,
    language: ‘US’,
    category: ‘Phones’,
    articlenumber: ‘6700’,
    name: ‘Sony Phone’
    properties: [
    {
        property: ‘Version’,
        helptext: ‘’,
        value: ’8.0’    
    },
    {
        property: ‘Operating System’,
        helptext: ‘’,
        value: ‘Android’
    }]
}
```

**Properties dataset**

```
[
    {
        id: ‘5b3603a56a14e1072ba6f4ef’,
        categoryPropertyId: ’429’,
        language: ‘US’,
        name: ‘Android’
    },
    {
        id: ‘5b3603a56a14e1072ba6f4ef’,
        categoryPropertyId: ’977’,
        language: ‘US’,
        name: ‘Version’
    },
    {
        id: ‘5b3603a56a14e1072ba6f4ef’,
        categoryPropertyId: ’1033’,
        language: ‘US’,
        name: ‘Weight’
    }
]
```

**Expected output**

```
{
    _id: 5b3f18d93098293c4ab0ca4a,
    created_at: ‘2018-07-06 09:22:45.377’,
    language: ‘US’,
    category: ‘Phones’,
    articlenumber: ‘6700’,
    name: ‘Sony Phone’
    properties: [
        {
            property: ‘Version’,
            helptext: ‘’,
            value: ’8.0’,
            categoryPropertyId: ’977’
        },
        {
            property: ‘Operating System’,
            helptext: ‘’,
            value: ‘Android’,
            categoryPropertyId: ’429’
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Can you post some example data. And what output you are expecting.

Comment: Hi Jack, I've added some example data in my post; plus the expected output.

Comment: Check answer if it solves your query?

Comment: Hi Jack, apologies for the late response. The code works perfectly but I noticed it doesn't take language into account. Any way have it also require another field to match? (Do I just add another equality match?)

Comment: What else you want to accomplish here? You can look up on one field only.

Comment: The helptext may vary for the property 'NFC' as the language might change. On the US site it'll have english helptext, but 'FR' for canada for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregations

Basically you need to first [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `"properties"` array to match with the foreign "name"... [`let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) allows you 
to keep the  field from root document(product) to the inner document(properties) and finally with the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) 
you can rollback the splitted "properties"  again to  the "properties" array.

If you have mongodb version 3.6

```
db.product.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$properties" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Properties.collection.name,
    "let": { "property": "$properties.property" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$name", "$$property" ] } } },
      { "$project": { "categoryPropertyId": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "properties.prop"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$properties.prop" },
  { "$addFields": { 
    "properties.categoryPropertyId": "$properties.prop.categoryPropertyId" 
  }},
  { "$project": { "properties.prop": 0 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
    "language": { "$first": "$language" },
    "category": { "$first": "$category" },
    "articlenumber": { "$first": "$articlenumber" },
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "properties": { "$push": "$properties" }
  }}
])
```

and if you mongodb version prior to 3.6

```
db.product.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$properties" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Properties.collection.name,
    "localField": "properties.property",
    "foreignField": "name",
    "as": "properties.prop"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$properties.prop" },
  { "$addFields": { 
    "properties.categoryPropertyId": "$properties.prop.categoryPropertyId" 
  }},
  { "$project": { "properties.prop": 0 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
    "language": { "$first": "$language" },
    "category": { "$first": "$category" },
    "articlenumber": { "$first": "$articlenumber" },
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "properties": { "$push": "$properties" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking your time to answer my question. I tested the code and it works. Only downside is that I get another field 'prop' with the id in and again 'categoryPropertyId' with that same id. So I get two fields with the same values. Also it doesn't take language into account, NFC has the same name but different help text per country; do I just add another $match?

Comment: which query you have tested? first or second?

Comment: I've tested the first query.

Comment: @BenRotsley You need to `$project` to remove the `prop` field...  I have updated the answer please check

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
db.getCollection("products").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$properties",
                includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                from: "properties",
                localField: "properties.value",
                foreignField: "name",
                as: "newData"
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$newData",
                includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                "language": "$language",
                "category" : "$category", 
                "articlenumber" : "$articlenumber", 
                "name" : "$name", 
                "properties": {
                  "property":"$properties.property",
                  "helptext": "$properties.helptext",
                  "value":"$properties.value",
                  "categoryPropertyId":"$newData.categoryPropertyId"
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $group: {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "properties": { "$push": "$properties" },
                    "language": { "$first": "$language" },
                    "category": { "$first": "$category" },
                    "articlenumber": { "$first": "$articlenumber" },
                    "name": { "$first": "$name" }
                }
        },

    ]

);
```

Hope this solves your query.